# Can I backup a MongoDB database using Git? Specifically, could I include the mongo data directory in the github repository?

Tags: git, mongodb, mongodb-mms

I'm fairly new to Node + Mongo, and I'm trying to see if there's a way I can back up my database every time I make a new commit. Is this possible? I know how to backup using mongodump, but I would prefer to avoid having to do this each time I push to the server. If the data directory idea doesn't work, would it be possible to write a script which backs up to my node server repository and then does the push every time I run it?

I haven't been able to find anything relating git and mongo online, so I think I may be looking at this wrong/don't understand something. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Late to the show, but I was also looking around and built a small Node.js script to do this: https://github.com/aramk/mongodb-git-backup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is MMS(Mongo monitoring service). It is a cloud based continuous backup service(plus lot of automation like on-demand restore,monitoring) offered by MongoDB. With MMS every single time you make a commit the DB gets backed up incrementally. It also possible to easily deploy and monitor standalone,replica-set or a sharded setup.

MMS is better compared to mongodump as it tends to do an incremental backup vs whole database backup.Writing a script which does mongodump on every commit will work but you will have to delete the old backup file every time you want to backup for a new commit. MMS cuts down on this devops overhead by manging all of this boiler-plate effort(writing scripts like mentioned) that goes into DBA's role.

Check-out this link for more info: [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com/)

Answer (score 8):

#### Git hooks

If you want to have some action triggered on every commit, `git` does have a notion of ["hooks"](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) that allow you to invoke executable scripts.

For example, you could add a `pre-commit` or `post-commit` hook that runs a `mongodump` backup (wrapped in a shell script) before or after a successful commit as appropriate.

#### Data directory

> Specifically, could I include the mongo data directory in the github repository?

I wouldn't include the data directory in your Git repository as the data files are locked for exclusive access when MongoDB is running. Copying files used by a running `mongod` instance may result in a corrupt or unusable "backup".

Binary data files will also significantly bloat your repository because they are (as at MongoDB 2.6) in an uncompressed binary format that includes some preallocated/unused storage. If you do want to store full data backups in version control, I would [backup with `mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-mongodump/) and compress the resulting output directory with zip or tar+gzip before checking into version control.

#### Alternatives

Taking full database backups on every commit could eat up a lot of time & disk space. Depending on your concerns/requirements for having a backup of your database on every commit, some alternative approaches to consider are:

- If you are concerned about a rogue commit deleting or altering data, a MongoDB replica set deployment with a [delayed secondary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-delayed-replica-set-member/) would allow you to keep an older view of data available (for example, delayed by two hours). This wouldn't replace a full backup strategy, but could be useful to keep your development workflow more agile while still providing some measure of data recovery on a bad commit.
- If you are more concerned about changes in the structure of your data or specific required data (rather than the full database), you could use a migration framework (e.g. [`mongo-migrate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-migrate)). Using explicit "migration scripts" to make changes to the structure of the data allows you to ensure that the data & structure matches what your code expects for a given checkout (associated .migrate scripts would be included with the code commit). This is also a helpful approach if you are working with a development team and want to try to ensure everyone has a similar data (without checking in full dumps).
- As @vmr mentioned, you can use a backup service like MMS (MongoDB Management Service) to take regular backups. The cloud version of MMS Backup can [restore to a point-in-time](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/tutorial/restore-from-point-in-time-snapshot/) within the last 24 hours.